# What is the lifetime of react context

Tags: r, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react.  In the examples I've found so far, using the react context api, you create your own context object and hand it as value to providers, etc.  All of the examples seem to store the entire context (either as one object or the sum of its parts) in state and utilize that for requests.  But what is the lifetime of the object?  Is it only created once during page refresh, or is it recreated during each render cycle such that it can only survive via useState or useRef?  In other words, is useState actually needed to store the context data between render cycles, or is useState only being used as a way to subscribe to changes?

This is the way I've been creating context based on the tutorials I've seen...

(To be clear, my question is about the lifetime of the "contextData" object in context.js, and whether rerenders or state changes or some other lifecycle event causes the script including the contextData instantiation and createContext to be rerun, or if some other weird interaction between createContext, contextData, and useContext is going on.)

### context.js

```
import React from "react";
const contextData = {
    prop1: "something",
    prop2: "somethingElse",
    func1: someFunction(stuff) {
        prop1 += ".";
    },
};
const myContext = React.createContext(contextData);
export {myContext};

function MyContextProvider({children}) {
   render <myContext.Provider value={myContext}>{children}</myContext.Provider>;
}
export default MyContextProvider;
```

### index.js

```
...
root.render(
   <MyContextProvider><App /></ContextProvider>
);
```

### SomeComponent.js

```
import {useContext} from "react";
import {myContext} from "./context"

function SomeComponent() {
    const ctx = useContext(myContext);

    return <span>{ctx.prop1}</span>
}
```

Comment: When the component with your provider is unmounted, you can't use the context in the children as 1) they would be unmounted as well 2) the provider no longer exists.

Comment: And yeah, context is like state; if you change it, it causes a rerender of the children inside the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tautological, but the context object is re-created whenever the function that creates it runs again. The function will (almost always) be either a component or custom hook.

The React philosophy is that the view should flow from the state, so state changes result in (functional) components running again to determine how to change the view (if at all). The same is true if state is included in a context object - if a state setter inside the context object is called, the functional component enclosing the initializer of that state runs again, resulting in a new object being passed down to consumers.

> In other words, is useState actually needed to store the context data between render cycles

Yes.

> But what is the lifetime of the object?

*One* particular context object will generally be garbage collected once there's been a re-render and no children reference the old object in a stale closure.

*All* context objects will get garbage collected only after the component surrounding the context provider unmounts.

---

With regards to the code in the question - by mutating an object that gets passed down, you're breaking the standard React workflow, which should avoid mutation for those sorts of values. It would be far better to call `.createContext` in a parent component and to pass down a state setter that changes the `prop1` property.

That said, if you don't do that - the top level of `context.js` only runs once, so you only create the object once, so that one object will exist forever. (which could be a mistake in case you ever change the code so that you want to use the context somewhere else too - the context value will include the old mutations)

Comment: I know that if I give the value property of the provider a new object, everything below that rerenders.  But in the examples I have, the context is created as a single object in a javascript file, createContext(thatObject) is exported, and then that context is given as the value to the provider.  So it seems that the actual object that is passed to createContext is above the lifetime of the provider and (in my case) I never regenerate that object.  So is the entire content of that js file wrapped in some function, such that it does get called again at some point?

Comment: If you declare an object at the top level of a file, that object will only be created once - which is a bad idea for values that may change, because it means the object can't be reused predictably. Better to put the object into state and to call a state setter when it needs to be changed.

Comment: Ok, I thought that was how it worked, but I wasn't positive about what React was doing under the hood.  I don't know ow or don't have the privilege to move to chat (I don't see a link anywhere) so if someone can, feel free.... I have a fairly large dataset that is interconnected and dynamic.  No single component knows how many pieces of state there need to be, and storing the entire object in state and rebuilding it (or rebuilding some {data: object} object just to get around rebuilding it) sits wrong with me.

Comment: However, any component that needs data from context that can change does know that it should be stateful.  So I plan on having those components subscribe to the individual properties and pass useState during that subscription.  If the context already has a useState for that property, it will return the existing one, ignoring the one passed in.  Otherwise, it will store the one passed in and return it.  In this way, every component can subscribe to a given component as if they are setting up their own state, but will actually be sharing the state.

Comment: And even with the overlap of the orphaned state objects, that's still going to be much less data in state than the entire context object, and much fewer components that would need to refresh after an update.  However, I haven't actually tested this at all yet.  I was currently just wanting to make sure that my map of property to state in the context wouldn't randomly disappear.  So I haven't tested that react will properly track state changes by the state reference being passed around, or it it only works off of the useState that is actually called in that component.